# How can I connect my Xbox to my Mac on my network

Tags: networking, powerline-networking

I have a wireless router/modem (Router 1) in my living room. This is connected to the internet (cable). Wireless is disabled as the router has a terrible wireless range. My Xbox is connected via ethernet to Router 1. Another LAN output from Router 1 connects to a powerline adapter. Router 1 acts as a DHCP server on 192.168.0.x and has the IP 192.168.0.1

In a second room I have Router 2. This has the powerline feed from Router 1 going into the WAN socket. This router runs the Tomato Firmware and acts as a wireless router for the rest of the house using the IP range 192.168.1.x. Router 2 IP is 192.168.1.1. My Mac is connected to Router 2 using a LAN cable and has the IP 192.168.0.133. Several mobile devices need wireless access. I want an ethernet connection to my Mac, not wireless.

I should be able to use software like Connect360 to share media from my Mac to the XBox but the XBox does not see my Mac. I can ping 192.168.0.1 from the Mac.

Is this possible using my current setup? If so, how?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "I want an ethernet connection to my Mac, not wireless"?

Comment: That is what I currently have. I just wrote that in case someone said 'oh just make a big wireless network' . I prefer to have a proper wired LAN connection on my main computer. The powerline connection via the two routers gives me a reliable and fast connection. I don't want to change that.

Comment: Do you have the firewall on router 2 turned off?

Comment: No. I don't currently have any rules for whatever file sharing / streaming protocol XBox uses.

Comment: Well it's a possibility that the firewall on router 2 is causing the connection to be blocked.

Comment: Should 192.168.1.x ips be able to automatically talk to 192.168.0.x ips then? I thought I would have to do some kind of routing.

Comment: Yeah it's not difficult. Just route to your mac from router 2. Although I suspect this may be the case, it could also be nothing. Worth a try though.

Comment: I tried opening all the relevant ports on Router 2. Still nothing. I cannot ping from Router 1 to my Mac. But it works in the opposite direction

Comment: I'm afraid I'm as flummoxed as you are at this point. I hope someone comes along with a proper answer.

Answer (score 0):

So, I got this working from reading a few other threads. Here's what I did

1.Disabled DHCP on Router 2.
2.Set Router 2 IP to 192.168.0.2
3.Set Router 1 to always give Router 2 the IP of 192.168.0.2.
4.Moved the powerline cable from the Internet/WAN port to a standard port on Router 2 (Don't know why I had to do this)

So Router 1 is now serving IP addresses via router 2 to wireless devices and my Xbox can now talk to my Mac.

My only remaining problem is that I can no longer access the Router 2 (running Tomato) homepage in a browser at 192.168.0.2. I can see it in the attached devices on Router 1 though. If anyone can explain a) exactly why the setup now works and b) why I can't access Router 2 in a browser I would greatly appreciate it!